# Getting a NameError when trying to alter a class variable in an outside function

Tags: python, audio-player

I am currently working on developing a jukebox/music player in python. In order to make the code more organized, I arranged it into specific classes. A few of the outside functions require accessing class variables and updating them. However, the program throws off the following error:

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "jukeboxDraft.py", line 77, in nextSong
    constructGUI.index += 1
NameError: name 'constructGUI' is not defined
```

The classes and the functions accessing the class variables are in the following code block:

```
import os
import pygame
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from tkinter import *
import eyed3

class JukeboxContent:
    def __init__(self):
        listOfSongs = []
        songTitles = []
        directory = askdirectory()
        self.listOfSongs = listOfSongs
        self.songTitles = songTitles
        self.directoryAsk = directory
        self.Error_NoMP3s = "No \".mp3\" files found."

    def directoryChooser(self):
        self.directoryAsk
        os.chdir(self.directoryAsk)

        for files in os.listdir(self.directoryAsk):
            if files.endswith(".mp3"):
                realdir = os.path.realpath(files)
                audioTag = eyed3.load(realdir)
                self.songTitles.append(audioTag.tag.title)
                self.listOfSongs.append(files)
                #print(files)

        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load(self.listOfSongs[0])
        pygame.mixer.music.play()



class JukeboxGUI(JukeboxContent):
    index = 0
    def __init__(self, window):
        JukeboxContent.__init__(self)
        self.back = Frame(master = window, width=500, height=500,  bg='pink')
        self.label = Label(window, text = "Jukebox")
        self.listBox = Listbox(window)
        self.nextButton = Button(window, text = "Next Song")
        self.previousButton = Button(window, text = "Previous Song")
        self.stopButton = Button(window, text = "Stop")
        self.labelVar = StringVar()
        self.songLabel= Label(window, textvariable = self.labelVar, width = 50)

    def constructButtons(self):
        self.back.pack()
        self.label.pack()
        self.listBox.pack()
        for items in self.listOfSongs:
            self.listBox.insert(END, items)
        self.nextButton.pack()
        self.previousButton.pack()
        self.stopButton.pack()

    def updateLabel(self):
        self.labelVar.set(self.songTitles[self.index])

#-------------------------JUKEBOX FUNCTIONS-------------------------------------


def main():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Jukebox")
    initiateJukebox = JukeboxContent()
    initiateJukebox.directoryChooser()
    constructGUI = JukeboxGUI(window)
    constructGUI.constructButtons()
    constructGUI.nextButton.bind("<Button-1>", nextSong)
    constructGUI.previousButton.bind("<Button-1>", previousSong)
    constructGUI.stopButton.bind("<Button-1>", stopSong)
    window.mainloop()

def nextSong(event):
    constructGUI.index += 1
    pygame.mixer.music.load(initiateJukebox.listOfSongs[constructGUI.index])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    constructGUI.updateLabel()

def previousSong(event):
    constructGUI.index -= 1
    pygame.mixer.music.load(initiateJukebox.listOfSongs[constructGUI.index])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    constructGUI.updateLabel()

def stopSong(event):
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    constructGUI.labelVar.set("")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How should I edit my "JukeboxGUI" class or the "constructGUI" variable to solve this? Any ideas?

Comment: Please include the complete Traceback (formatted as code) - it will show which line is causing the error.

Comment: `constructGUI` only *exists* within `main()`'s scope. You aren't *passing it around* to the other functions so they don't know what it is.Here are some things from the docs to read: [Naming and Binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding), [A Word About Names and Objects and Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects).

Answer (score 0):

`constructGUI` is defined in `main`, so it won't be accessible outside of that function.

Make `constructGUI` a global variable by putting a placeholder outside of the function in the global scope. If you need to modify it within a function (which it looks like you are), make sure to add `global constructGUI` to the top of that function.

Answer (score 0):

`constructGUI` only *exists* within `main()`'s scope. You aren't *passing it around* to the other functions so they don't know what it is.

Make `constructGUI` a module level object so that *everyone* can see it.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #main()
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Jukebox")
    initiateJukebox = JukeboxContent()
    initiateJukebox.directoryChooser()
    constructGUI = JukeboxGUI(window)
    constructGUI.constructButtons()
    constructGUI.nextButton.bind("<Button-1>", nextSong)
    constructGUI.previousButton.bind("<Button-1>", previousSong)
    constructGUI.stopButton.bind("<Button-1>", stopSong)
    window.mainloop()
```

---

Here are some things from the docs to read: [Naming and Binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding), [A Word About Names and Objects and Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects).